# "API" list item in the footer is misaligned on smaller-width viewports

Tags: bug, status-review, design, footer

Here is a screenshot (freehand red circle included) of the "API" list item misalignment when the `@media screen and (max-width: 980px)` media query kicks in for viewports of less than `980px` width:

[image: screenshot of the footer section with the "API" list item misaligned]

The "API" and "Data" list items constitute a separate *semantic* group, however, they are considered to be a part of the "Stack Exchange Network" unordered list in the HTML markup with only *visual* separation (via the `mt16` CSS class increasing `margin-top` for the *first* element which happens to be the "API" list item).

The above obviously leads to the "API" list item being pushed to the bottom. Moving the two list items to a `<ul>` and applying `mt16` class to it would have prevented the issue from happening (content simplified for brevity):

```html
<ul class="-list">
<!-- first group of list items -->
</ul>
<ul class="-list mt16">
  <li>API</li>
  <li>Data</li>
</ul>
```

[image: screenshot of the fixed footer section]

Comment: Seems our `md:mt0` class is not taking effect. On it!

Comment: Looks like this has since been fixed.

Comment: @CaveJohnson looks like it has been indeed - I suppose the post will get a status-completed in the customary 6-8...

Answer (score 3):

This bit of CSS also causes trouble in the normal view:

[image]

Where there is a white row between all the different elements. This might be intentional, but then this is the wrong fix for the "problem".

The right fix would be to apply a `margin-bottom` to the previous element in the list, as that doesn't offend the display when shrinking to different screen widths.

**Using Margin bottom on "Business"**

Full width: 
[image]

Medium width: 
[image]

Small width: 
[image]

Comment: I assume the separation is intentional. And yeah, another way to fix the alignment issue is to apply `margin-bottom` instead, agreed.